# Html navigate to same directory

Tags: php, html

I have a directory with 2 files in it

http://domain.com/folder/index.php and 
http://domain.com/folder/page.php

On index page I am trying to make a link that redirects to http://domain.com/folder/

if I make a link like this

```
<a href="#">Go to Index</a>
```

it won't refresh the page and if I keep it empty like this

```
<a href="">Go to Index</a>
```

it will get link on any page I am in on same folder. If I was here http://domain.com/folder/page.php that link will be like

```
<a href="http://domain.com/folder/page.php">Go to Index</a>
```

Then how can I make a link to index page again instead of I put index.php?

Comment: You can use `/folder` in href parameter. Another thing is you can use meta base tag to specify root folder to your `folder` and then you can use `/` in your href parameter.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: @tilz0R how i don't get it dear ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

You can use a relative link:

`<a href="./page.php">Go to page.php</a>`

or if you are on page.php

`<a href="./">Go to index.php</a>`

This will look inside the containing folder of the page you are changing from.

---

You can use a root path like @tilz0R suggested and declare a [base href](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp):

```
//on index.php
<head>
  <base href="http://domain.com/folder/" target="_blank">
</head>
//on page.php:
<a href="/">Go to Index</a>
```

Comment: dear, but i don't want to use "index.php"